# Angular dependency provider is not providing the specified alternate class

Tags: angular

I'm writing a component unit tests for my `doc-manager.component` component. `doc-manager.component.ts` utilizes the `DocService`, which I'd like to replace with instances of `MockedDocService` in my unit tests.

[Using alternative class providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#alternative-class-providers), different classes can provide the same service to a component. In the `providers` array, I'm using this feature to return an instance of `MockedDocService` every time the component requests a `DocService` instance.

Take particular note of the `{ provide: DocService, useClass: MockedDocService }` line.

```
fdescribe('DocManagerComponent downloadDocumentation', () => {
  let component: DocManagerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DocManagerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DocManagerComponent,
      ],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: DocService, useClass: MockedDocService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should pass this test', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HelpManagerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.doSomething();
    expect(component.documentExists).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

The `component.doSomething()` function depends on `DocService`. However, because I'm using alternate class providers, I'm expecting `MockedDocService` to be utilized every time the component calls a `DocService` function. This does not happen. The component is still using `DocService`, and `MockedDocService` is never utilized.

Any ideas about what I need to do to replace `DocService` with `MockedDocService`?

Comment: Where is the actual DocService provided, in the production code? In the module? In the component?

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark; try moving your fixture and component instance creation into the beforeEach block, after the compileComponents. Use them throughout your tests (as opposed to creating new instances). This also assumes you are providing the service to the module the same way you're providing it in the test (at the module level that the component is a member of), not by creating instances of it or injecting it directly into the component.

Comment: Can you show the module code that you provide the service in?

Comment: @TimConsolazio Thank you! You response lead me the the solution. Inside of `doc--manager.component`, I was injecting the `DocService` directly into the component. I modified the component to provide the service the same way I am in the tests (using imports), and that resolved the problem. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: I will gladly reap the benefit of an accepted answer, which I'll post now :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are providing the service in the module that the component is a member of. Not creating instances of it manually, or injecting it directly into the component. If you provide it at the module level in the test, but the component level in the code, you'll get inconsistent results. Or, change the way the test creates/provides the service to match your production code.